# How to set the week start day in a pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am trying to filter data in a pivot table. I need to set Monday as the first day of the week. The default is Sunday. Do you know how to set it?

Edit1: I am trying to do dynamic filtering using THIS WEEK. As the default is Sunday, the result is not what I exactly expect.

Edit2: Current solution using VBA. I am still looking for a neater solution.

```
Sub YmThisWeek()
'
' YmFinal Macro
'

'
    Dim startDate, endDate As Date

    endDate = Date
startDate = endDate - 7 ' 7 DAYS IN A WEEK

'Pick the star of the week
'vbSunday    1   Sunday (default used)
'vbMonday    2   Monday
'vbTuesday   3   Tuesday
'vbWednesday 4   Wednesday
'vbThursday  5   Thursday
'vbFriday    6   Friday
'vbSaturday  7   Saturday


Do While (startDate < endDate - 1) And Not Weekday(startDate) = 2 '<- week start day

    startDate = startDate + 1

Loop

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pvtTbl").PivotFields("Date").ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pvtTbl").PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters.Add Type:= _
    xlDateBetween, Value1:=Format(startDate, "dd/mm/yyyy"), Value2:=Format(endDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know how to do that, but with Dates in the row areas, consider "grouping" by days, in groups of seven, starting with a Monday.  Not the same as filtering, but maybe it will work for you.  With VBA, you could set the filter to "This week" with a starting date of Monday by using the macro to select the relevant dates to show.

Comment: Thanks @RonRosenfeld , but data grouping doesn't work for me. Can you explain how to set the starting date using VBA macro?

Comment: You'll need to educate yourself about VBA, if you aren't already knowledgeable.  But one process would be to iterate through the PivotItems in the "Date" PivotField and compare each one against an array of Dates that are the range that you have defined; set the Visible property to either True or False depending on whether they match.  You'd then have only the dates you want showing in the Rows area.  You can get some idea by recording a macro to select the dates you want from the drop down above the Rows area. However, I have a non-VBA method that I will post

Comment: Thanks @RonRosenfeld , what I have done so far is to record a vba macro that does the filtering using DateBetween. Then I defined two variables to replace value1 and value2. Value2 is current Date and using a while loop, value1 is set to closet Monday (using value2).
Then, I let the filter method to take care of selecting the data in range value1 and value2.
I thought there must be a method or property that provides the useres with such option! Something like "ThisWeek.StartDay = 1"
I am curious to see the non-VBA method!

Answer (score 1):

Good question. And I don't have the perfect answer.
But this workaround might get you going.

- Click on 'Sunday'
- Drag it to the end of the Pivot table

[image]

Comment: I've edited my question. This not the order that matters, I need to get the data from Monday to Sunday rather than Sunday to Saturday!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with VBA.  But a NON-VBA method you could use involves adding an extra column to your data.  Label it **THIS WEEK**.  Then populate that with a formula that returns TRUE or FALSE depending on your definition of the week.  For example, if **THIS WEEK** is from the most recent Monday to the following Saturday, compared with a date stored in cell F1, then the formula would be:

```
=AND(A2>=($F$1+1-WEEKDAY($F$1-1)),A2<=($F$1+7-WEEKDAY($F$1-1)))
```

I used a cell reference for testing purposes, and I would advise you to do the same until you have things working the way you want.  You can subsequently either change your cell so it contains **=TODAY()**, or you can substitute **TODAY()** in the formula.

You would then drag **THIS WEEK** to the filter area and filter on **TRUE**  Whenever you Refresh your Pivot Table, the filter will update.